# jQuery Fullcalendar: trigger a "create" event using Capybara

Tags: capybara, fullcalendar

I want to trigger a "create" event in jQuery Fullcalendar using Capybara, but I don't know which element to click. I'm not sure whether this is possible with Capybara anyway...

Comment: Did you get any answer from elsewhere?

Comment: Sadly, no. Didn't find any.

Comment: After which user action is `create` event trigered? It would be also good if you'll point me to documentation about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/Y6mqc/) where if a user clicks on a calendar day a new calendar event is created.

See the [***dayclick callback***](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) code:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    if (allDay) {
        alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
    }else{
        alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
    }

    // change the day's background to highlight the fact that its been clicked
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    // Create a new event for the day that was clicked
    var myEvent = {
      title:"my new event",
      allDay: true,
      start: date,
      end: date
    };
    cal.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent );
}
```

You can then click on a date in jQuery Fullcalendar (which will trigger the creation of a new event when the above code is in place) using Capybara as follows:

```
page.find(:css, "td[data-date='2013-11-06']").click()
```

Note that you'll need to tailor the CSS to choose exactly which FullCalendar day (i.e. TD element) to click, but this is just an example.

See the Caybara documentation [***here***](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#finding) for how to do this.

Comment: I didn't have the time yet, but I will try to do it soon. I'm sorry for the delay, much work to do here. ;)

Comment: I still didn't have the time yet. But I marked it as the answer so you get your bounty points. I will definitely come back to this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No you left it to late, the bounty has been wasted "If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.". Never mind! Let me know how you get on.